# non alignment of base layer and other vector layers

Tags: qgis, data, spatial-database, analysis, spatial-analysis

i'm sure you've encountered this problem repeatedly. i've tried all different methods.

1. Enable on the fly crs transformation.
2. go to settings and options to use crs data.
3. go to properties and change the coordinate system to the same one.

I'm using google street as my base map.

CRS of vector data WGS84/48N

metadata is -

```
                                            General
Storage type of this layer
ESRI Shapefile
Description of this provider
OGR data provider (compiled against GDAL/OGR library version 1.11.2, running against GDAL/OGR library version 1.11.2)
Source for this layer
C:\Users\hp 1.000\Desktop\GIS\weatherdata.shp
Geometry type of the features in this layer
Point
The number of features in this layer
1253
Editing capabilities of this layer
Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries, Simplify Geometries, Simplify Geometries with topological validation
Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 11303.3,25898.2 : xMax,yMax 44627.4,46712.2
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: The listed extents don't make sense for a UTM zone. X (easting) values should be between 200km and 800km, so either the data's actually in zone 47 or the layer spatial reference system is incorrect. Can you go back to the data provider to see what they say?

Comment: If sourced from a Singapore agency, it's more likely EPSG::24500 (Kertau 1968 / Singapore Grid) or the newer EPSG::3414 (SVY21 / Singapore TM).

Answer (score 2):

Step 3 of your list is definitely **wrong** in most cases. It spoils your data, because it does not change the coordinates itself, only the CRS.

Instead, you have to save the data from the untouched CRS to another filename and CRS.

For the Google background of the Openlayers plugin, project CRS and the CRS of the Google layer **must** be EPSG:3857. Other layers may have different CRS.

---

**Update**

Whoever told you that the data is in UTM 48 N is wrong. Singapore is 149km north of the equator, and that is way off the extent of your data.

My best bet for Singapore is EPSG:3414 SVY21 / Singapore TM, et voilá:

[image]

The extent fits perfectly to Singapore. So in this case, you can use `Set CRS for Layer` to change the wrong CRS to the right one.

Comment: Hi AndreJ. thanks for pointing that out.. May i ask... do i still have to alter on the fly crs transformation to EPSG: 3857 then? Also, if you dont mind, could you please elaborate what you meant by 'Instead, you have to save the data from the untouched CRS to another filename and CRS.'?

Comment: Hi AndreJ. thanks for pointing that out.. May i ask... do i still have to alter on the fly crs transformation to EPSG: 3857 then? Also, if you dont mind, could you please elaborate what you meant by 'Instead, you have to save the data from the untouched CRS to another filename and CRS.'?

Comment: Would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add which CRS and extent your vector layers have, as reported by Properties, metadata tab?

Comment: hi AndreJ I've added the information you needed in the main comment above.